# Business hours disappear

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I installed fullcalendar with the following configurations:

```
businessHours: [$heureDay],
```

$heureDay contains this code :

```
Array(11) 0: 
 {dow: Array(1), start: "9:00", end: "12:00"}dow: [1]start: "9:00"end: "12:00"proto: Object1: dow: [1]start: "13:30"end: "17:00"proto: Object2: {dow: Array(1), start: "9:00", end: "12:00"}3: {dow: Array(1), start: "13:30", end: "17:00"}4: {dow: Array(1), start: "9:00", end: "12:00"}5: {dow: Array(1), start: "13:30", end: "17:00"}6: {dow: Array(1), start: "9:00", end: "12:00"}7: {dow: Array(1), start: "13:30", end: "17:00"}8: {dow: Array(1), start: "9:00", end: "12:00"}9: {dow: Array(1), start: "13:30", end: "17:00"}10: {dow: Array(1), start: "9:00", end: "12:00"}length: 11__proto__: Array(0)
```

But in my calendar the business hours disappear as the day progresses (cf [PJ),] but other day business hours are good :

[image]

Why?

Comment: hello, can you improve your question in putting your configuration in code bloc and in putting directly your image in question using simply Paste/Copy. Can you also give more information. It is your first post on StackOverflow. Can you make some effort so that other users can help you ?

Comment: Can you show the businessHours data in JSON format please? It's unreadable like that, I have no idea what it's trying to represent.

Comment: Which version of Fullcalendar you use, and put your codes